# Disadvantages/Vantages for calling web API client-side

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I'm starting a web application that interacts with many web services. I ask you what do you think about calling these web services with javascript.

My Opinion:
Vantages:
- bandwidth savings (server-side)
- no client-server communications (for only reading operations)
- what else?

Disadvantages:
- code readable
- what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side:

- Caching is simpler
- no need to worry about malicious JSON
- no same-domain restrictions.
- every request has more network latency

Client side:

- fewer application layers
- doesn't introduce more network latency when accessing the api
- requires client-side templating, or sending data back to the backend

Answer (score 1):

Are these services going to exist on different domains?  If so, you will have to deal with cross domain AJAX calls; The services you interact with will have to support something like JSONP or CORS, the latter of which is fairly new and only supported by modern browsers.

Comment: yes, they exist on different domains but all these services support JSONP.